# Round of total from average query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

can anyone help me with my query...in my current query i calculate the average of the total score of a specific person and the out is like `4.232398` i want it to round of automatically the final score so that is not decimal type output....can anyone help me with that.

my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
(SELECT SUM(t2.inttotal)
 FROM app_interview2 AS t2 
 WHERE t2.atic = t.atic)/7
 AS interview_sum,

(SELECT SUM(o2.ototal)
 FROM other_app2 AS o2 
 WHERE o2.oaic = t.atic)/7
 AS other_sum,

atid,
atic,
atname,
region,
town,
uniq_id,
position,
salary_grade,
salary
FROM app_interview2 AS t
WHERE uniq_id = '$q'
GROUP BY t.atname HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.atic)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT ROUND(SUM(t2.inttotal), x)` where x is number of decimals you need.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you wantto combine interview_sum and other_sum (you don't specify)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
(SELECT SUM(t2.inttotal)
 FROM app_interview2 AS t2 
 WHERE t2.atic = t.atic)/7
 AS interview_sum,

(SELECT SUM(o2.ototal)
 FROM other_app2 AS o2 
 WHERE o2.oaic = t.atic)/7
 AS other_sum,

ROUND(SUM(interview_sum,other_sum)),

atid,
atic,
atname,
region,
town,
uniq_id,
position,
salary_grade,
salary
FROM app_interview2 AS t
WHERE uniq_id = '$q'
GROUP BY t.atname HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.atic)
```

Comment: inteview_sum and othersum are different

Comment: i just want to round of the output of interview_sum and other_sum separately.

Comment: then just round them separately then you never stated if you wanted them combined or not but either way the point is still use the ROUND() function